# Angular 2: router not in app component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create a page with a login in the app component html, then, when the user sign in, I want to go to another view, could be: dashboard, and in the dashboard show the menu of navigation.

How can I do that correctly?

Can I  put the tag

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In a differnt view that app.component and make it works?

thank u!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a router guard for this.

[Here is a great article about protecting routes](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html)

With a guard you can protect certain routes in your application for example if I go to /dashboard and I'm not logged in I'll get the login page and after I log in I could go to the /dashboard route.

Comment: sounds great, let me check.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in app.module.ts you have to import the router module as well:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

and in the imports -section there needs a line like

```
RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
```

where ROUTES is a definition of your routing information, e.g.

```
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: 'videos',
    component: VideosComponent,
  }
];
```